# Symfony2 FormType bindRequest binds 000 as null

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

Symfony2 forms bind 000 input as null, is this intended?

```
// FormType
    $builder
        ->add('dummy', 'text');

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        dump($data); // This correctly dumps dummy as 00000
    }
// Input 00000 in to the field and submit to controller

// Controller
    $form = $this->createForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        dump($form->getData()) // dummy dumps as null, if i change the field type to integer, it dumps as 0, rather then 00000
    }
```

Comment: We need some more information to spot your issue. What kind of data to you bind to your form? What is your `createForm()` method doing. Do you have any other listeners?

Comment: Nothing, the rest is standard, symfony 2.8